# Counting number of classes in the list: same function return different result

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2013

So I have such list

```
List<single_request> list_Srequests =   new List<single_request>();
```

And I have added some classes into it. And I need count the number of classes, which equals to `int totalNum_SingleReg;`.

```
totalNum_SingleReg = list_Srequests.Count; // this call return true number, 
                                           //  that equal to 8
```

However this one eventually num is equal to 68:

```
foreach (single_request sRequest in list_Srequests)  
     {            
        totalNum_SingleReg++; 
     }
```

I can't  understand what wrong with last one. Any ideas?

Comment: What sort of scope does `totalNum_SingleReg` belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may have some other code between your item counts, If you need check the list count and foreach count, try below code

```
var count1 = list_Srequests.Count;

var count2 = 0;

foreach (var sRequest in list_Srequests)  
{            
        count2 ++; 
}

if(count1  == count2 )
   Console.WriteLine("COUNT1 EQUAL TO COUNT2");
```